# React Bootstrap Carousel issue: While sliding the image breaks and shows a blank background

Tags: reactjs, carousel, react-bootstrap

[image: Carousel image while sliding]

While sliding the image breaks and shows a black background where as it should slide-out/In along with the the next/prev image and there should not be any space between slides
Even copied it from bootstrap website and imported to react in a new component but still the issue persists

Even copied it from bootstrap website and imported to react in a new component but still the issue persists

Comment: Please provide some code so that others can understand the issue and help.

Comment: The same Code of react Bootstrap Carousel that's on official web
//


function UncontrolledExample() {
  return (
    <Carousel>
      <Carousel.Item>
        <img
          className="d-block w-100"
          src="holder.js/800x400?text=First slide&bg=373940"
          alt="First slide"
        />
        <Carousel.Caption>
          <h3>First slide label</h3>
          <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
        </Carousel.Caption>
      </Carousel.Item>
     
    </Carousel>
  );
}

export default UncontrolledExample;

Comment: Please post the code in your question even if its from an official library. Most probably, some css you added/have in your code is messing up the slider. Unless you post these css/html/js , people won't be able to help